# How to put sounds in an image and preventing it from doubling the sound when touched?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am doing an app that needs images to be simultaneously touched and produce a sound for each image. So far I've done making an image be touched and will produce a sound. But unfortunately every time it's being touched the sound double. And also when it is being touched then drag to the whole screen, the sound still plays. I've tried researching in making the boundaries be set so it will allow me multi-touch but I have no luck. So my main problems are: How to set the multi-touch in my layout? and for the sounds to not be doubled.

Comment: Please, share Your code. Probably, it's a bug in yours touch handling.

Comment: hi i just fixed the sound being doubled. thanks for replying. my only problem is the multi-touch on an image. I am using the function onTouchListener.